# How to fix this RSpec error with Mongoid? "can't convert Symbol into Integer"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, mongoid

I'm writing tests for my controller. They are very simple, but this error has kept popping up. This is my controller

```
  def show
    id=params[:id]
    @user=User.find(:first,id)
  end
```

My test

```
  before(:each) do
    @user = Fabricate(:user)
    sign_in @user
  end
  ...
  it "should be successful" do
    get "show", :id => @user
    response.should be_success
  end
```

And the error message

```
  1) UsersController GET 'show' for the logged in user should be successful
     Failure/Error: get "show", :id => @user
     TypeError:
       can't convert Symbol into Integer
     # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:6:in `show'
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your controller is where the mistake is.  The find method automatically only returns the first result (it is equivalent in code to `User.where(:id => params[:id]).first`).  Try removing the :first symbol and simply pass in id (`User.find(id)`)

Comment: I get another error when I do that: `BSON::InvalidDocument: Cannot serialize an object of class User into BSON.` I'm using Mongoid, but the API is roughly the same as ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

> `get "show", :id => @user`

Your problem here is likely with `@user`, whose value in the context of your spec is not clear from the example you've posted.  You should be passing an integer record id as the value for the [params argument to get](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-get), for example `:id => 1`.